# How to use easing in the jQuery plugin jQuery.ScrollTo?

Tags: jquery, easing

The [website](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) only mentions the easing option:

```
# easing: Name of the easing equation.
```

But there's no example.

How to use this feature?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The examples are here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Use like so:

```
$.scrollTo( '#options-examples', 800, {easing:'easeOutQuad'} );
```

These easing functions don't come built in though. You can use the [jQuery Easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). This then supplies the following easing functions:

- jswing
- easeInQuad
- easeOutQuad
- easeInOutQuad
- easeInCubic
- easeOutCubic
- easeInOutCubic
- easeInQuart
- easeOutQuart
- easeInOutQuart
- easeInQuint
- easeOutQuint
- easeInOutQuint
- easeInSine
- easeOutSine
- easeInOutSine
- easeInExpo
- easeOutExpo
- easeInOutExpo
- easeInCirc
- easeOutCirc
- easeInOutCirc
- easeInElastic
- easeOutElastic
- easeInOutElastic
- easeInBack
- easeOutBack
- easeInOutBack
- easeInBounce
- easeOutBounce
- easeInOutBounce

Comment: The default easings are "swing" and "linear" if you don't want to use the easing plugin.

Comment: Here's a helpful website I found that helps you choose an easing function: http://easings.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default usage here: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Here is an example of 'easeOutQuad':

```
function (){
 jQuery.easing.def = 'easeOutQuad';

 $('#options-examples').on('click','a', function() {
   $('#another-option-examples').slideToggle(1000);
   return false;
 });
}
```