# Large Angular app scrolling in IE11 is not smooth if listening for scroll events

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

I am working on large angular app and I have a couple of scroll listener to adjust positions. When user scroll in major browsers, all is good but in IE 11, the scrolling is delayed for about 2 seconds and it's not smooth.

When debugging, I isolated the problems and by removing scrolling listeners, it fixed the issue and the scrolling was smooth in IE. The problem is that even empty scroll listener is creating this unpleasant delay scrolling experience. In other angular apps I've worked with, listening for scrolling didn't cause any issue in IE.

I am looking for any suggestions or ideas what could go wrong and how to fix it.

The way we listen in the app is by `HostListener('window:scroll')` but I tried to change it also to directive and subscription with the method `fromEvent` or the `window.addEventListener('scroll')` but no differences.

Performance in IE11 on scroll:

[image]

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE 11? Could you please provide [a minimal sample which can reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue? You could use online editor like [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)  to provide the sample. With only the above description, we can't reproduce the issue and see how to help.

Comment: Hi @YuZhou I added performance screenshot in IE11. It's large app so I am trying to isolate the issue but so far didn't find where it is. Suspected zone library but no luck. Also tried to remove majority of ngFor loops but still very poor.

Comment: From the screenshot you providing, I can only tell the DOM event(scroll) takes a bit long time. Have you investigated deeper which function in it takes the most of the time? You can also compare the performance of DOM event(scroll) in IE with in other browsers to see where the difference is. Maybe that can help to narrow down the issues.

Comment: Besides, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033878/angular-2-rc-5-internet-explorer-10-poor-scroll-performance) seems to be helpful. It says the problem is that IE is firing way too many scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in IE. Please use code snippet like below and also maintain pagination and limit the records <= 200 per instance.

In Html:

```
 *ngFor="let data of array | async;index as i; trackBy: trackByFn(index)"
```

In Component:

```
trackByFn(index) {
return index;`enter code here`
```

}